# Verbatim environment in \newcommand

Tags: macros, verbatim, renewcommand

I want to make two commands for `\begin{verbatim}` and `\end{verbatim}` to make it shorter like this:

```
\newcommand{\bv}{\begin{verbatim}}
\newcommand{\ev}{\end{verbatim}}
```

I have already done the similar with an `itemize` environment:

```
\newcommand{\bi}{\begin{itemize}}
\newcommand{\ei}{\end{itemize}}
```

The last one works. But the verbatim case does not work because the verbatim-mode applies immediately when defining new commands. Is it possible to implement what I intend? I've tried some statements with `\expandafter`, `\noexpand` and `\csname...\endcsname` but could not achieve the result. I need a kind of short alias for `\begin{verbatim}` and `\end{verbatim}`.

Comment: you can not use verbatim in the argument of another command (including definitions) inside verbatim `\ ` is not special so `\ev` would just be that literal string and the environment will not end.  Although using `\bi` happens to work for `itemize` it's a bad style it confuses editors and syntax checkers and human readers of the source. Most editors will add an environment such as `\begin{itemize}..\end{itemize}` with two or three key strokes so the definitions do not help typing the document.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I didn't think it's a bad style to use such short aliases for environments. Maybe I should refuse from the idea.

Comment: it happens to work for `itemize` but it fails for `verbatim` and fails (for different reasons) for any amsmath environment such as `align` it also fails with `tabularx` and fails with any environment defined with `\NewDocumentEnvironment` `b` argument

Comment: Thank you, I got it. In general, is it a good style to make shorten forms for long-written commands using `\newcommand` such as `\Longrightarrow` -> `\Lra` or `\varepsilon` -> `\ve` ? Or it's better to use the original forms of the commands?

Comment: that is less problematic (but I wouldn't do it) if you are going to define such aliases I'd use semantic names so if Longrightarrow is being used as implication, or some kind of function map or ... give it a name rerlated to the use, if you just rename it `\Lra` it just makes it harder to read.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can re-define LaTeX's verabtim, but it is more tricky. You have to start a catcode dancing and re-define internal LaTeX `\@xverbatim` macro:

```
\def\bv{\begin{verbatim}}
{\catcode`\@=11 \catcode `|=0 \catcode`\\=12 |gdef|@xverbatim#1\ev{#1|end{verbatim}}}
```

Testing:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\def\bv{\begin{verbatim}}
{\catcode`\@=11 \catcode `|=0 \catcode`\\=12 |gdef|@xverbatim#1\ev{#1|end{verbatim}}}

You can try:
\bv
A verbatim
text is here # \ ^ ?
\ev

Next text.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Whether defining shorthand macros for calling the macro `\begin` and/or for calling the macro `\end` works out or fails depends on how the environment in question works.

At the time of reading input from a .tex-file TeX takes the content of that file for a constellation of instructions for appending so-called tokens to the token-stream.
After reading and tokenizing everything in TeX is based on tokens.
Macro programming and performing assignments is based and focused on tokens.

For example the phrase `\begin{foo}` occurring in the .tex-file usually yields appending the tokens <kbd>\begin</kbd>, <kbd>{<sub>1</sub></kbd>, <kbd>f<sub>11</sub></kbd>, <kbd>o<sub>11</sub></kbd>, <kbd>o<sub>11</sub></kbd>, <kbd>}<sub>2</sub></kbd> to the token-stream.

The control word token <kbd>\begin</kbd> denotes an instance of the macro `\begin`. The explicit character tokens <kbd>{<sub>1</sub></kbd> and <kbd>}<sub>2</sub></kbd> denote the tuple of tokens which form the argument of this instance of the macro `\begin`. The explicit character tokens <kbd>f<sub>11</sub></kbd>, <kbd>o<sub>11</sub></kbd>, <kbd>o<sub>11</sub></kbd> are the argument of this instance of the macro `\begin`.

The most important things whose carrying out is triggered by `\begin`, i.e., by `\begin{⟨name of the environment to begin⟩}`, are:

- Opening up a new local scope.
- Saving the name of the environment to begin, which comes from the argument of `\begin`, to the macro `\@currenvir`. When `\end{⟨name of the environment to end⟩}` is reached, `\@currenvir` is used for triggering an error message in case the name stored in `\@currenvir` does not match the ⟨*name of the environment to end*⟩ given with `\end{...}`.
- Via `\csname⟨name of the environment to begin⟩\endcsname` creating and appending to the token stream a control sequence token whose name comes from the argument of the macro `\begin`. Usually that control sequence token denotes a macro for initiating the carrying out of whatsoever actions which are a specific for the environment in question.

Analogously the phrase `\end{foo}` occurring in the .tex-file usually yields appending the tokens
<kbd>\end</kbd>, <kbd>{<sub>1</sub></kbd>, <kbd>f<sub>11</sub></kbd>, <kbd>o<sub>11</sub></kbd>, <kbd>o<sub>11</sub></kbd>, <kbd>}<sub>2</sub></kbd> to the token-stream.

The most important things whose carrying out is triggered by `\end`, i.e., by `\end{⟨name of the environment to end⟩}`, are:

- Triggering an error message in case the name of the current local scope/the ⟨*name of the environment to begin*⟩ stored in `\@currenvir` does not match the argument of the macro `\end`/does not match the ⟨*name of the environment to end*⟩.
- Via `\csname end⟨name of the environment to end⟩\endcsname` creating and appending to the token stream a control sequence token whose name has the prefix "end" and where the remainder of the name is the ⟨*name of the environment to end*⟩. That token may denote a macro for, when the local scope opened via `\begin{...}` is about to be closed, initiating the carrying out of whatsoever actions, which, too, are a specific for the environment.
- Closing the local scope.

(I said "the most important things" because both with `\begin` and with `\end` actually some more things are done—especially since the new hooking system was established in LaTeX 2ε, but knowledge of these things is not needed for understanding why with some environments defining shorthand macros for calling `\end{...}` does not work out.)

Under usual circumstances you can write, e.g., a shorthand macro where expanding yields the tokens <kbd>\end</kbd>, <kbd>{<sub>1</sub></kbd>, <kbd>f<sub>11</sub></kbd>, <kbd>o<sub>11</sub></kbd>, <kbd>o<sub>11</sub></kbd>, <kbd>}<sub>2</sub></kbd>.

Under usual circumstances these tokens coming into being in the course of reading/tokenizing lines of the .tex-file or coming into being in the course of expanding a shorthand macro doesn't matter.

But some environments work in a different way.

E.g., the environment verbatim.

The purpose of that environment is to typeset material as is, which in the .tex-file is placed in lines between the lines `\begin{verbatim}` and `\end{verbatim}`.
The purpose of that environment is to cause TeX to not take input coming from the .tex-file and following `\begin{verbatim}` for control sequences that are to be carried out and whose usual definition/usual meaning is to be looked at, but to take subsequent input coming from the .tex-file for something that is to be typeset as is, without looking at the usual definition/meaning, without expansion, without whatsoever other ways of carrying out.

So the phrase `\end{verbatim}` in the .tex-file is a marker for ending typesetting things as they occur in the .tex-file.

The concept of typesetting as is until encountering a marker in the .tex-file implies that defining a shorthand macro for that marker does not work out:

If in the .tex-file, instead of that marker, something different occurs that is intended to be a shorthand for that marker, how can TeX know that this time the usual definition is to be obeyed instead of not looking at it but typesetting the characters that form the shorthand as is?

`\begin{verbatim}` yields tokens <kbd>\begin</kbd>, <kbd>{<sub>1</sub></kbd>, <kbd>v<sub>11</sub></kbd>, <kbd>e<sub>11</sub></kbd>, <kbd>r<sub>11</sub></kbd>, <kbd>b<sub>11</sub></kbd>, <kbd>a<sub>11</sub></kbd>, <kbd>t<sub>11</sub></kbd>, <kbd>i<sub>11</sub></kbd>, <kbd>m<sub>11</sub></kbd>, <kbd>}<sub>2</sub></kbd> as usual.

Internally via `\csname..\endcsname` you get a control sequence token `\verbatim` which initiates the carrying out of actions which are a specific for the environment verbatim.

The most important ones of these actions are:

- Change the category code régime so that tokenization of any of those characters, whose occurrence in the .tex-file at some stage of processing the input coming from the .tex-file usually triggers TeX into doing some special action, just yields an ordinary character token of category 12(other) where no special action is related to, but which is something that—in case a font for doing so is in use— leads to typesetting a character, just like `!` in the .tex-file usually is tokenized as <kbd>!<sub>12</sub></kbd>, which in turn may lead to typesetting an exclamation-mark.
  E.g., `$` usually gets tokenized as <kbd>$<sub>3</sub></kbd> and that token, when reaching TeX's stomach, triggers toggling math mode. E.g., `\` (backslash) in the stage of reading and tokenizing lines of input from the .tex-file usually is a trigger for starting creating a control sequence token.
  In verbatim category code régime such things are not the case but tokenizing such characters yields ordinary explicit character tokens  of category 12(other) which do not cause TeX to perform special actions, and which, in case a font for doing so is in use, can be typeset like, e.g., an exclamation-mark.
- Read and tokenize stuff from the .tex-file linewise and typeset it in a monospace font. Until encountering the case that reading and tokenizing a line of the .tex-file yielded the tokens <kbd>\<sub>12</sub></kbd>, <kbd>e<sub>11</sub></kbd>,  <kbd>n<sub>11</sub></kbd>,  <kbd>d<sub>11</sub></kbd>,  <kbd>{<sub>12</sub></kbd>, <kbd>v<sub>11</sub></kbd>, <kbd>e<sub>11</sub></kbd>, <kbd>r<sub>11</sub></kbd>, <kbd>b<sub>11</sub></kbd>, <kbd>a<sub>11</sub></kbd>, <kbd>t<sub>11</sub></kbd>, <kbd>i<sub>11</sub></kbd>, <kbd>m<sub>11</sub></kbd>, <kbd>}<sub>12</sub></kbd>.

But when instead of the phrase `\end{verbatim}` the call to a shorthand macro is typed in the .tex-file, this case cannot occur and at some stage of processing you get some error message which is likely to seem inscrutable when you are not familiar to how TeX works and how things like the environment verbatim are implemented in LaTeX.

The gist is: Defining and using a shorthand macro for calling `\end{⟨name of the environment to end⟩}` only works out in cases where `\begin{⟨name of the environment to begin⟩}` does not initiate the carrying out of an algorithm whose termination depends on without expansion encountering a specific constellation of tokens which serves as a marker for having reached the end of the bit of .tex-file-input forming the body of the environment and terminating the algorithm.

With the environment `verbatim` the constellation of tokens forming the "end marker" is: <kbd>\<sub>12</sub></kbd>, <kbd>e<sub>11</sub></kbd>,  <kbd>n<sub>11</sub></kbd>,  <kbd>d<sub>11</sub></kbd>,  <kbd>{<sub>12</sub></kbd>, <kbd>v<sub>11</sub></kbd>, <kbd>e<sub>11</sub></kbd>, <kbd>r<sub>11</sub></kbd>, <kbd>b<sub>11</sub></kbd>, <kbd>a<sub>11</sub></kbd>, <kbd>t<sub>11</sub></kbd>, <kbd>i<sub>11</sub></kbd>, <kbd>m<sub>11</sub></kbd>, <kbd>}<sub>12</sub></kbd>, i.e., stuff that comes into being while tokenization takes place under the verbatim category code régime.

As both the body and the end-marker of the environment verbatim need to be read from the .tex-file and tokenized under verbatim category code régime, things like

```latex
\newcommand\macro{%
  \begin{verbatim}
  ...
  \end{verbatim}
}%
```

also don't work out because here everything that should be tokenized under verbatim category code régime gets tokenized under usual/default category code régime when tokenizing and carrying out the `\newcommand`-directive and its arguments.

But there are also environments where both the body of the environment and the constellation of tokens forming the "end marker" of the environment is to come into being while tokenization takes place under the usual/default category code régime. But with such environments still the constellation of end marker tokens is expected to be found and not a constellation of tokens forming a shorthand for that.

But with such environments you can do things like

```latex
\newcommand\macro{%
  \begin{foo}
  ...
  \end{foo}
}%
```

because here expanding `\macro` also delivers the tokens forming the correct end marker.